# mysql server in linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I am unable to resolve issue with mysql in linux
A few days ago, I deleted mysql, then I installed again, but now I am unable to use mysql.

Whenever I am using mysql I am having this error:

**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

If I am install the mysql-server again then I get:

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
  mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```